# Is it always possible to find a decomposition of cubic graphs into paths with average length three, and why?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that the degree of every vertex of a cubic graph is three, so every vertex should be either a starting point or a finishing point of a path in decomposition. But I can't tell whether is it possible to decompose a cubic graph into paths with average length three.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this works: Let $F\subset G$ be a subgraph of $G$ in which every degree is odd. You can obtain this graph by deleting edges of cycles while possible. Suppose $F$ has a minimum number of edges. Note that $F$ is a spanning forest, which we can decompose in $n/2$ paths $P_1,\ldots, P_{n/2}$. The new graph $G'=G-E(F)$ has maximum degree at most $2$, so it is a set of vertex-disjoint paths and cycles. Orient these paths and cycles in a way that every vertex has at most one in edge and at most one out edge. For each path $P_i$ we add the out edges of $G'$ in its end vertices (if any). This process should decompose the graph. The new added edges do not form cycles because of the minimality of $F$.

Comment: In particular, if your graph has a perfect matching, then every path in the obtained decomposition has length 3.

Answer (score 0):

If a graph with $n$ vertices can be decomposed into $m$ paths, we have $2m$ ends of paths. As you found, in a cubic graph each vertex is start or end of exactly one path, so $n=2m$. Also, the number $e$ of edges can be obtained from the hand-shaking lemma: $2e=3n$ implies $e=\frac32n=3m$. Es $e$ is also the sum of all path lengths, the average path length  is $\frac em=3$.

So all it takes is to obtain just *any* path decomposition.
Just pick a path $v_1\ldots v_k$ of maximal length. By the cubic property, $v_k\ne v_1$. Remove the edges of this path. Remove all vertices of degree $0$. Resolve all vertices of degree $2$. Show that the resulting smaller graph is either empty (so we are done) or is cubic again (though possibly not simple, but who cares); that is: why can't we be left with a cycle? Apply induction.

Comment: If all it takes is to obtain just *any* path decomposition, why not simply decompose the path into graphs of length $1$?  I think you want a decomposition into at most $n/2$ paths where $n$ is the number of one with exactly vertices. Then, by splitting longer paths into shorter ones as needed, you can get a decomposition into exactly $n/2$ paths, so the average length will be $3$.

Comment: Another thing I don't understand about your answer is "By the cubic property, $v_k\ne v_1$. It seems to me that $v_k\ne v_1$ by the definition of a path. However, if you consider a cycle to be a kind of path, then such cubic graphs as $Q_3$ have a Hamiltonian cycle. And what's with "Remove all vertices of degree $0$"? Removing the edges of a path from a cubic graph can leave edges of degree $1$ or $2$ or $3$ but not $0$. And, while I don't expect to see a counterexample, it doesn't seem obvious to me how to prove rigorouslyh that yhour procedure won't end up with more then $n/2$ paths.

Comment: In my first comment, "graphs of length $1$" was meant to be "paths of length $1$".